# Объясните, как работают команды?

Tags: linux, ос, astra-linux

Объясните, как работают команды?
Первая команда:

```
touch file.txt && echo "Some string" > file.txtm && cat file.txt
```

Вторая команда:

```
echo -e "b\nd\nc\na\nd\ c" >> file.txt && sort -u < file.txt
```

Comment: Во-первых, это не одна большая команда, а несколько отдельных никак не связанных маленьких команд, которые зачем-то слепили в одну строку через `&&`. Во-вторых, а что конкретно не понятно-то?

Comment: в первой "команде" есть ещё похоже и ошибка - лишняя буква m в txtm

Comment: не понятно как работают эти команды.

Comment: МАЛЬЧИКИ, ЕСЛИ НЕ ХОТИТЕ НЕ ОТВЕЧАЙТЕ НО НЕ НУЖНО ПИСАТЬ ЛИШНИЙ ТЕКСТ ЧЕ ПОНЯТНО ЧЕ НЕ ПОНЯТНО. Я РАДА ЧТО ВАМ ПОНЯТНО ВСЕ НЕ ВСЕ УМНЫЕ ТАКИЕ КАК ВЫ.

Comment: Гуглю документацию за вас: [touch](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=touch&category=1), [echo](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=echo&category=1), [cat](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=cat&category=1), [sort](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=sort&category=1&russian=0), [перенаправление ввода-вывода](https://younglinux.info/bash/input)

Comment: не гугли просто мимо тогда иди и все

Comment: @Ирина, я всё понимаю, но всё-таки первые два комментария по делу.

Comment: @AlexF, вы забыли про `&&`.

Comment: я так и не получила ответ на свой вопрос может кто то подробнее объяснит ?

Comment: Вряд ли кто-то вам будет подробнее объяснять то, что уже достаточно подробно расписано во всевозможных учебниках и прочих пособиях по линуксу

Comment: @Ирина, можно узнать, откуда вы взяли эти строки? Лабараторка в вузе? Или бесплатный онлайн курс? Это не похоже на код для продакшена.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> touch file.txt && echo "Some string" > file.txtm && cat file.txt
> ```

- Команда touch file.txt создает файл в вашей текущей директории. Дальше автор использует && для слепления нескольких команд в одной строке, что и делает в следующих шагах.
- Использует echo "Some string" > file.txtm для записи строки "Some string" в файл file.txt, скорее всего лишняя буква m в file.txtm является опечаткой.
- cat file.txt выводит результат записи в файле на экран терминала.

> ```
> echo -e "b\nd\nc\na\nd\ c" >> file.txt && sort -u < file.txt
> ```

- Повторяются такие же действия с записью в файл echo -e "b\nd\nc\na\nd\ c" >> file.txt, только с добавлением [опции -e](https://mb4.ru/programming/bash/1252-echo-synopsis-options.html).
- sort -u < file.txt помогает отсортировать строки в записанном файле, выводя это на экран терминала. Подробнее про опцию -u можно прочитать [здесь](https://losst.ru/komanda-sort-v-linux).